# My portable HDD cannot be mounted into filesystem -- can't read superblock

Tags: mount, ext4

I have a Seagate portable hdd 1 TB formatted fat32. Now I had no problems at the very beginning, but now I am getting the following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/zorobabel/EFI: 
Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,
shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/zorobabel/EFI"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: 
mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock
(udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Same on ext4, and ext3 on 2 computers.
Same on Windows.

Disks application displays:
Partition Type: EFI System
Contents: FAT32

## REEDITED

Mounting:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 seagate
mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock
```

Therefore I no longer can access the data to backup, nor to format it.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l


    Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204885504 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525167 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x99bd9cd1

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdb1               1  1953525166   976762583   ee  GPT
```

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: I edited my answer. It looks like is visible /sda2. It cannot be mounted.

Comment: I don't see any sdb disk. BTW your mount command will fail since you should use `mount /dev/deviceid /mountpoint` you are doing it backwards. BTW, didn't you used `sudo fdisk -l`? with **sudo**?

Comment: @Braiam sorry I did: 
`$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 seagate`
`mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock`, where sdb1 is indeed visible at `fdisk -l`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information.

Comment: @Braiam. I recently re-edited it.